# How to check and fix PIA VPN's DNS resolver issue?

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, dns, vpn

By default on Linux Mint 18 is `/etc/resolv.conf` a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

```
ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Dec 1 11:04 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

after launching Private Internet Access (PIA) VPN application version 75, the symbolic link gets re-written with a standard file:

```
ll /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root vlastimil 52 Dec 2 11:10 /etc/resolv.conf
```

with contents

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218
```

as the picture depicts:

[image: PIA DNS resolver]

However, not always it reverts the resolver back to the symbolic link.

---

How to check for it and fix this PIA DNS resolver issue, after I disconnect?

I'd prefer shell-script solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've already contacted PIA support team and they're working on a fix.*

Non-the-less, here some code, that could easily check for the issue and fix it, if it occurs:

```
function pia-after-fix {
    if [ -L /etc/resolv.conf ]
    then
        echo "It does not need fixing."
    else
        sudo ln -sf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
    fi
}
```